# How to align NSSting from right side

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, foundation

[image]> I have attached an image of two receipt. i wan to print same as right side receipt. This is how i am doing at our end. Please suggest.

```
 for ( items in _invoceNew.items)
{
    NSString *itemString = items.itemName;
    if ([itemString length] == 0)  {
        itemString = @"Item";
    }
    NSString *invoiceFormat = items.quantity;
    invoiceFormat = [invoiceFormat stringByAppendingString: items.amount];
    NSString *joinString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%-2s %-20s %1s\n",[items.quantity UTF8String], [itemString UTF8String] ,[items.amount.asLocaleCurrency UTF8String] ];
    const char *join = [joinString UTF8String];
    [_myPos POS_PrintText: join x:0 nWidthTimes:0 nHeightTimes:0 nFontType:0 nFontStyle:0];
}
```

> Amount  should be align from right hand side. so that it will not go in second line.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is homework question

Comment: What is `_myPos`?

Comment: its a object of BLR printer library

Comment: Can the BLR printer library print right aligned strings?